# Add two Different Google Forms data into one spread sheet as different columns

Tags: google-docs, google-apps-script

I have basically two different forms on my google site.

I want to add two different google forms data into one spread sheet with different columns titled as.

So, what kind of google apps script I need to put there in my code.

I don't know about the way...How to do that?

Please tell me the way .. how to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do that.

a) One is to have the two forms feed data into separate spreadsheets and then write a script to reconcile the entries on every submission (depends on what criteria you want to apply).

b) The other option is to design your forms using Apps Script UI and then have the form submissions going into the respective columns.